# Why is the use of memory mapped buffers in shapefile data stores not recommended on Windows?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, geotools

When creating a shapefile data store, you have the option to enable 'memory mapped buffers'. Both GeoServer and GeoTools recommend to disable this on Windows.

[GeoServer docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/vector/shapefile.html):

> Enables the use of memory mapped I/O, improving caching of the file in memory. **Turn off on Windows servers.**

[GeoTools docs](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/shape.html):

> Optional: memory map the files (not recommended for large files under windows, defaults to false)

What is the reason for this recommendation? The only seemingly related resource I found is [a discussion from 2004](https://sourceforge.net/p/geotools/mailman/message/10722347/), but I don't know if it still applies or if it is actually related to the mentioned documentation.

> I've discovered why the shapefile data store test fails on windows.
>   Basically, the datastore is closing a reading channel on a file in
>   order to overwrite it with a new file that was build while using
>   the writer. Now, this triggers an exception because you cannot open
>   a file for writing that still has a memory mapper part, and the
>   memory mapped part is still there by contract (sigh!).
>
> [...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it still applies, also, as far as I know, on Windows memory mapping actually reserves memory, while on Linux is just a direct conduit to the kernel without the OS actually loading the full file right away (it's seen as virtual memory). My experience is on Linux it helps performance without visible ill side effects, on Windows unless you actually have the physical memory you're in trouble. Things might have changes since that, it was several years ago.